# need to pass ~a id="myID" onclick=cEdit("var1","var2")>Display Text </a~ as an exact string to a plug-in

Tags: c#, string, escaping, sequence, literals

Good morning Team,
    I am new to this site, but have found it helpful over the last several months.  I have a challenge with MVC .net core 2.2 and c#.  I am hopeful this forum may be able to help.

I need to pass the following string into a property of a plug-in:

~a id="myID" onclick=cEdit("var1","var2")>Display Text~/a~

I can build a string that (using the text visualizer) looks like this, but what is actually being passed to the plugin property is:

~a id=\"myID\" onclick=cEdit(\"var1\",\"var2\")>Display Text~/a~

This results in the HTML being written  as:

~a id=\"myID\" onclick=cEdit(\"var1\",\"var2\")>Display Text~/a~

This obviously does not work.

I have tried

```
    string ss = @"~a id=""myID"" onclick=cEdit(""var1"",""var2"")>Display Text ~/a~";

    string ss = @"~a id=\"myID\" onclick=cEdit(\"var1\",\"var2\")>Display Text ~/a~";

    string ss = @"~a id=\"myID\" onclick=cEdit(\"var1\",\"var2\")>Display Text ~/a~";

    ss = ss.replace(“\\”,”\”)
```

My Code:

(controller)

```
private OrgModel.OrgChild GetChild(string mgrId, string Org_CD, string Div, string strClass)
    {

        OrgModel.OrgChild rtnChild = new OrgModel.OrgChild();
        …
         Detail code
        …

  string ss = @"<a id=""myID"" onclick=cEdit(""var1"",""var2"")>Display Text </a>";

        rtnChild.name = ss;
        rtnChild.title = strName;
        rtnChild.className = strClass;

        return rtnChild;
    }
```

My Code ( JavaScript)

```
~script~function cEdit(var1,var2) {alert(var1 + " - " + var2);}~/script~
```

I want to pass the exact string to the plugin as:

~a id="myID" onclick=cEdit("var1","var2")>Display Text ~/a~

NOTE: Please replace ~ Character with the appropriate < or > character. They are swapped to ensure proper display.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand is that you are trying to pass a html value set on your controller to a plugin on your view.

What I have checked so far is that hidden input can hold the model html value correctly.

```
@model MyModel
@{
    string myHTML = Model.MyHTMLValue;
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

@Html.Hidden("someHTML", myHTML)

<script>
    $(function () {
        console.log($('#someHTML').val());
    });
</script>
```

Further, have a look at [Decode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility.htmldecode?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Thanks for the response Marissa,

Comment: Thanks for the response Marissa,  Unfortunately this method has the same problem.  It still adds the \ in front of the Unicode representation of the character.  Example "\&#39;"

Comment: I have created a prototype to show the problem and opened a ticket with Microsoft. They have acknowledged the problem and have escalated it. Once I get a definitive response, I will post it here.

Answer (score 0):

According to Microsoft, this is not possible with C#.  You will need to pass \' to java script and then replace \ with \, leaving you with the desired \'.